# How to pass on results from package blockCV to package sdm

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am working on species distribution models and I am using the function `sdm` in package sdm to construct my models. I try to implement a blocked cross-validation using the function `spatialBlock` in the package BlockCV, but I don't seem to find how to pass on the result of `spatialBlock` to my `sdm` function in the sdm package.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that there is an option for it. There should be an argument that accepts the FoldIDs. A workaround is that you write it in a for loop like any other modelling method (see blockCV's vignette) if your goal of using spatial CV is model evaluation.

You can email the maintainer as well.